# data is posting as anonymous user in the data base when posting from postman

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, postman

This is my entity class where it is having createdBy and lastModifiedBy fields. When ever I'm posting the data from postman for the fields 'createdBy' and 'lastModifiedBy' the columnn in the database is saving as anynomous user instead of the name which is posting from the postman

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //@CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
    //@JsonIgnore
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    //@LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
    //@JsonIgnore
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
```

From the UserRequestDTO it is posting the request which is given below

```
UserRequestDTO.class


@Data
public class UserRequestDTO  {
    @NotBlank
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, name = "UserName must be between 3 and 255 characters long", position = 0)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 255)
    private String userName;

    private NameDTO name;

    @NotBlank
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, name = "displayName must be between 3 and 100 characters long")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String displayName;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "1")
    private Long organizationId;

    @Lob
    private String photo;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "India")
    private String country;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "bhargav")
    private String createdBy;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "bhargav")
    private String lastModifiedBy;
}
}
```

This is the data which I'm trying to post from the post man.

```
{

            "userName": "jaya",
             "displayName": "jay",
             "country":"USA",
             "createdBy":"bhargav",
             "lastModifiedBy":"jaya krishna",
             "phoneNumber":"9876543210",
             "email":"jaya@abc.com",
             "startDate":"2019-12-08",
             "endDate":"2020-01-08"

        }
```

But the createdBy column and the lastModified column is saving as the anynomous user instead of the name which is posting from the POSTMAN. datatype of both the columns is varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the User Entity witch you are trying to persist in the Database, also if you can share how you are mapping DTO with Entity Object.